# How to add sequence of rendering to dynamically loaded elements with Animate.css

Tags: jquery, animation, animate.css

I am adding some dynamic elements into the page with Animate.css but as you can see they all appears on the page together. How can I leverage the rendering by appearing the item on page one by one instead of loading at once?

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $("#result").append('<div class="box animated fadeInDown"></div>')
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-PHcOkPmOshsMBC+vtJdVr5Mwb7r0LkSVJPlPrp/IMpU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<button>Append Data</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Check animate.css delay function here; https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md#delay-class  Should be pretty straightforward to set delay programmatically in your for loop and addClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are with `setTimeout`:

```js
const delay = 50; //milliseconds
$("button").on("click", function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => $("#result").append('<div class="box animated fadeInDown"></div>'), i * delay)
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-PHcOkPmOshsMBC+vtJdVr5Mwb7r0LkSVJPlPrp/IMpU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<button>Append Data</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```